# Join two tables, get all results from first table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

So I have two tables. Let's say this is the structure of the tables:

```
     TABLE A      |        TABLE B       |
-----------------------------------------|
    ID   |   div  |   ID   |  date | val |
-----------------------------------------|
     A   |   a    |    A   |   d1  |  22 |
     B   |   b    |    B   |   d2  |  10 |
     C   |   c    |    C   |   d3  |  9  | 
     F   |   l    |    F   |   d1  |  10 |
```

What I want is to have this result:

```
 row 1: A, a, null, null
 row 2: B, b, d2, 10 
 row 3: C, c, null, null
 row 4: F, l, d1, 10
```

It's a left JOIN but I want to retrieve only the values that have val = 10.

I am using SQLite. I have tried many answers from different threads without any success.

Comment: The `where` clause is applied to the ***results*** of the `join`. In your case, such a `where` clause would exclude any rows with a `null` value in `b.val`, due to there being no matching row in `b`. So, you need to filter the table either before the join, or during the join. Adding `and b.val = 10` to the join predicate is the latter of those two options, and the normal choice.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `left join`:

```
select a.*, b.date, b.val
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id and b.val = 10
order by a.id;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot the where clause. Can you check again my question?